How can a tkinter button dynamically control the content of other buttons?
I tried to create some buttons and the content (picture) of these buttons is dynamically controlled by another button.
E.g.
The buttons A and B are controlled by the buttons C and D.
If I was to press C, then A would be assigned 'Pic1' and B 'Pic2'
and if I I was to press button D then A would be assigned 'Pic3' and B 'Pic4'.
If I was then to press C once again, A would be assigned 'Pic1' and B 'Pic2'.
I already tried to code the button explicitly like this:
def my_command(value):
    print (value)
    return

button= Button(win, image=tes[0],command= lambda: my_command(1),borderwidth=0)
button.grid(row=0,column=0)
button= Button(win, image=tes[1],command= lambda: my_command(2),borderwidth=0)
button.grid(row=0,column=1)

This one works fine pressed 1  my_command(1) returns Button:1 if pressed 2 my_command(2) returns Button:2) 
BUT when I put it in a for-loop like this:
j=0
for i in f1:
# file up a list of pic from files, f1 is a list of valid file names
    click_btn1= PhotoImage(file=i)
    tes.append(click_btn1)
#set the image of the button
    img_label= Label(image=tes[j])
# assign button and command
    button= Button(win, image=tes[j],command= lambda j=j:
    my_command(j),borderwidth=0)
    button.grid(row=0,column=j)
    j +=1

The buttons are displayed and I can click them but my_command(j) returns "Button:2"
every time, no matter which button is pressed(1 or 2)

Does it helping changing command=lambda j=j: my_command(j) to command=lambda j=j: my_command(j + 1)?

Cannot reproduce the issue.  I got 0 when clicking the first button and 1 for the second button.

@Qualcuno2 no unfortunatly

@acw1668 This is the part which works. The logic is as follows
1st row pictures
2nd row numbers (e.g. 1 and 2)
I do have a set of default pictures but when I do press the Key with the 2 (row 2) I want the buttons in row 1 to change the pictures to another set.
And if I press the Button labelled 1 again back to the default picture set.

Why don't you post the code with issue instead?

@acw1668 thank you very much for your effort to understand my somehow strange communication :)  -
Both examples are "working" without runtime error. But are NOT doing what I wanted them to do. I want a window where one row shows Buttons (I can press) but the content (Labels of buttons, or Pic) change dynamically based on which button I print in the second row. I couldn't find a way to do that in tkinter.  Thanks again

No one can help if you don't post what you have tried, i.e. a [mre].

@acw1668 thank you I know ... I did some further investigation and found my solution. Redefining the content of a button after creation ...
I am using now button.config(image='new image') in my 'command-function'

solved problem using button.config(image='New image')
